# NSComboBox value getting and assigning it to a label

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscombobox

I am new to Mac development. I want to **get the value selected from a combo box and assign it to the text of a label** in a Mac app using Objective-C. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following  gives the selected value:

`[yourComboBox objectValueOfSelectedItem]` returns `id`. Have a try with following, if in case you may require to type cast it to `NSString`.

```
[self.yourLabelOutlet setStringValue:[yourComboBox objectValueOfSelectedItem]];
```

**Not checked, but something similar to this*

***EDIT:***

Find a [Sample Project](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6347535/comboboxdemo-zip-35k?da=y).

Comment: @SharadMhaske: check for the sample project.

Comment: -[NSComboBoxCell objectValueOfSelectedItem] should not be called when usesDataSource is set to YES

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer only works when your `NSComboBox` does not use its own dataSource

When using your own dataSource for your `NSComboBox` you should approach it like this:

```
[yourDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:[yourComboBox indexOfSelectedItem]]);
```